# Power Automate Error "Send an HTTP request SharePoint"

Tags: sharepoint

What am I missing?

- SharePoint Site name: cBEYONDataManagers
- List Name: Project Scorecard
- Field trying to update the default value: ReportMonthYear

  - It's a date field

I'm getting an error

[image]

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"headers": {
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=ddcb58f4e7d4612fd9d0aff3394b5e86024fefcfe9489e80129e4b872a8b7da9;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-cus.azconn-cus-002.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=ddcb58f4e7d4612fd9d0aff3394b5e86024fefcfe9489e80129e4b872a8b7da9;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-cus.azconn-cus-002.p.azurewebsites.net",
    "x-ms-request-id": "5ea8d3a0-908c-3000-fd7e-e2b35a59d695",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
    "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
    "Date": "Thu, 24 Aug 2023 16:20:39 GMT",
    "Content-Length": "472",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Expires": "-1"
},
"body": {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetByTitle.\r\nclientRequestId: d4bf88c8-24b4-4631-9b13-6a58e99eb8d4\r\nserviceRequestId: 5ea8d3a0-908c-3000-fd7e-e2b35a59d695",
    "source": "https://cbeyondata.sharepoint.com/sites/cBEYONDataManagers/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Project%20Scorecards')/Fields/getbytitle('ReportMonthYear')",
    "errors": [
        "-1",
        "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to update the column settings/definition or value in the column for a specific list item/record? I think you want to update the list item, can you confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to update the information of the date column of the item?

Here, it is recommended to obtain the item ID through get items traversal, and then update the information of the date column through the method below
Here is list：
[image]

You can get metadata by this way
[[image: get metadata1]

[image: get metadata]

Get item id
[image: Get item id]

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test111')/items(@{items('Apply_to_each')?['ID']})




 {
      "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.TestListItem"
      },
     "Title": "New title",
     "YOUR datetime name": "2020-11-24T18:39:05Z"
    }
```

[image: post datetime]

Here is test result:
[image]